# A function for calculating the eigenvalues of a matrix in R

Tags: r, eigenvector, eigenvalue, linear-equation

I want to write a function like `eigen()` to calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an arbitary matrix. I wrote the following codes for calculation of eigenvalues and I need a function or method to solve the resulted linear equation.

```
eig <- function(x){
       if(nrow(x)!=ncol(x)) stop("dimension error")
          ff <- function(lambda){
                for(i in 1:nrow(x)) x[i,i] <- x[i,i] - lambda
                }
det(x)
}
```

I need to solve `det(x)=0` that is a polynomial linear equation to find the values of `lambda`. Is there any way?

Comment: Try `optim` function.

Comment: or `uniroot` to find the root ?

Comment: But `optim()` finds the roots that minimize the function. I want to solve it, something like `polyroot()`.

Comment: did you google "[r] nonlinear root finding" ... ?

Comment: Yes, I searched for it. The resulted equation is linear. I didn't find any thing.

Comment: I'm unclear why the answer is not: `myeig <- function(mat) eigen(mat, only.values-TRUE)`

Comment: I want to write my function! Not using `eigen()`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution using `uniroot.all`:

```
library(rootSolve)
myeig <- function(mat){
  myeig1 <- function(lambda) {
    y = mat
    diag(y) = diag(mat) - lambda
    return(det(y))
  }

  myeig2 <- function(lambda){
    sapply(lambda, myeig1)
  }
  uniroot.all(myeig2, c(-10, 10))
}

R > x <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3)
R > eigen(x)$values
[1] -1.77461906 -1.21589769 -0.01010515
R > myeig(x)
[1] -1.77462211 -1.21589767 -0.01009019
```

Comment: you have the right tools, but can you write one `myeig` function that only takes a matrix as input and returns the eigenvalues?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I wrapped up and updated it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you liuminzhao. For determining eigenvectors I should solve another system of linear equations for every eigenvalue. This is the codes I wrote using your help: 
`for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){ 
solve(mat-values[i]*diag(nrow(mat)),rep(0,nrow(mat)))}`
But this returs just zero vector that isn't a eigrnvector. How can I find this answer?

Comment: Can `uniroot.all()` find the complex roots in `myeig2` in above example? If no, which function can do such?

Comment: @Mahmood I don't think it can do that. [polyroot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/polyroot.html) can find complex roots, but I think you need to get the polynomial coefficients first.

Comment: This solution does not  work for all matrices, e.g., `R <- matrix(c(1, .5, .5, .5, 1, .5 , .5, .5, 1), 3 , 3)`

Answer (score 1):

Computing determinant is such a bad idea as it is not numerically stable. You can easily get `Inf` etc even for a moderately big matrix. I suggest reading the following answers (read them otherwise you have no idea what my code is doing):

- [Are eigenvectors returned by R function eigen() wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52458862/4891738)
- [eigenvectors when A-lx is singular with no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52844991/4891738)

then use either of the following

```
NullSpace(A - diag(lambda, nrow(A)))
nullspace(A - diag(lambda, nrow(A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @liuminzhao won't work if there is two repeated eigenvalues. The function will fail to find the roots, because the characteristic polynomial of the matrix will not change sign (it is zero and does not cross the zero line), which is what `rootSolve::uniroot.all()` is doing when looking for roots. So you need another way to find a local minima (like `optim()`). Moreover, it will failed to determine the number of repeated eigenvalues.

A better way is to find the characteristic equation with, which is easily done with `pracma::charpoly()` and then using `polyroot()`.

```
par <- pracma::charpoly(M) # find parameters of the CP of matrix M
par <- par[length(par):1]  # reverse order for polyroot()
roots <- Re(polyroot(par)) # keep real part of the polyroot()
```

The `pracma::charpoly()` is not too complicated in itself, see its source [code](https://rdrr.io/cran/pracma/src/R/charpoly.R), starting at line `a1 <- a`.